# python mysql connection error MAX_QUESTIONS resource

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-connector-python

I am fetching data periodically (every 20min) from a MySQL database in a small server. My dataflow has been running smoothly for 2 weeks until today it broke and got

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1226 (42000): User 'HH' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 60)
```

I tried to restart the script but kept getting the same errors. Each time when my script runs, it makes 8 queries so total 24 queries per hour, how am I exceeding the resource? And each of the query is pretty simple, I ask for records that has a certain station ID and after a certain timestamp. Here are the two functions I use to request the data

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector as mysql
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    def grabSoilAfter(self, lastTime, station_name, sensor_id):
        
        db = mysql.connect(
            host = self.host,
            user = self.user,
            database = self.database,
            password = self.password
            )
        cursor = db.cursor()
        

        cols = ['data' + str(k) for k in range(0, 7)]
        cols_str = ', '.join(cols)
        

        sql_command = "select add_utc, " + cols_str + ' from weatherdata' +   \
                        ' where station_ID = \''+station_name +     \
                        '\' and add_utc > \'' + lastTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + '\' ' +   \
                        'order by add_utc asc'   
        cursor.execute(sql_command)
        dat = cursor.fetchall() ## it returns a list of all databases present
        dat_pd = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ['time_utc','4inch', '8inch', '12inch', '16inch', '20inch', '24inch', '28inch'])
         
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        
        return dat_pd

    def grabWeatherAfter(self, lastTime, station_name, sensor_id):
        
        db = mysql.connect(
            host = self.host,
            user = self.user,
            database = self.database,
            password = self.password
            )            
        cursor = db.cursor()
        
        cols = ['data' + str(k) for k in range(0, 7)]
        cols_str = ', '.join(cols)
        

        sql_command = "select add_utc, " + cols_str +' from weatherdata' +   \
                        ' where station_ID = \''+station_name +     \
                        '\' and add_utc > \'' + lastTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + '\' ' +   \
                        'order by add_utc asc' 
        dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql_command, db)
        db.close()
```

For function `grabWeatherAfter()` I use `pandas.dataframe.read_sql_query` to auto format the data. What should I do to decrease my `QUESTIONS` to below `60`?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that "max_questions" is some kind of translation issue around "max_connections", you probably need to stop initializing a new database connection for every query and instead reuse a connection.

Comment: My db admin also thinks it's an unsuccessful disconnection issue. But I close each cursor and connection after every single query, I am not sure why it's not disconnected properly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on `phpmyadmin` or `mysql console` but the user you are logged in should have permissions to make these changes.

Run it just like a normal query, doesn't matter which database is selected. Important thing is that your db user should have privileges for this.

For unlimited, you can set `max_questions` to 0 or you can set it to any specific value

```
SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=0;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```